# "It's not every day"

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Is (a) a reduced form of (b)?

> a. It's not every day he visits Laura.

> b. It's not the case that every day he visits Laura.

Comment: Not necessarily. The sense is 'not _every_ day, only _some_ days' - but, as SegNerd says, it's an idiom.

Comment: What is the meaning of b?

Comment: Example (b) is an unlikely sentence, but it could conceivably be used if someone had made a statement  which took it for granted that 'he' visited Laura every day, and another person objected "Well, actually that _isn't_ the case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“It’s not every day” is an idiom that means “It’s unusual.” If something happened every day, it would be a usual or normal thing to happen. So if something unusual happens, you can say “It’s not every day that (something happens).”